# How to load a user field in template_preprocess_comment()

Tags: 7, theming

I added a country field to users and want to show it below the username on comments (in the Bartik theme).
How can I load that field into the `bartik_preprocess_comment()` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drupal already loads the user object. You can see the user object on that function:

```
function bartik_preprocess_comment($variables) {
  $user = $variables['user'];
  // Full load user
  $user = user_load($user->uid);
  // Now access your field
  $country = field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_country');
  if ($country) {
    $variables['author_country'] = $country[0]['safe_value'];
  }
  else {
    $variables['author_country'] = '';
  }
  // On your comment.tpl.php using $author_country
}
```

Comment: fantastic! Thanks so much for the detailed help!!! For future reference here are the 2 lines to get the country name and a icon of the country flag:   `$variables['user_country_name'] = $country[0]['safe'];
    $variables['user_country_flag'] = theme('countryicons_icon', array('code' =>  $country[0]['iso2'], 'iconset' =>  'shiny')); `

Comment: `$variables['user']->uid` is the user ID for the user who is viewing the comment, not the user who created the comment. This code is showing the flag of the user who is viewing the comment, not the comment author. See the other answer. It's a shame users need to read two answers, and the comments for the first answer to understand which answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

[template_preprocess_comment()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/template_preprocess_comment/7), the preprocess function that is called before `MODULE_preprocess_HOOK()` and `THEME_preprocess_HOOK()`, uses `$variables['user']`, but from the code it is using, I take that variable contains the user object for the user who is viewing the comment; differently the CSS class it is adding would not be "comment-by-viewer" (`$comment->uid` is the user ID for the author of the comment).

```
if ($comment->uid === $variables['user']->uid) {
  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'comment-by-viewer';
}
```

If you want to load any field associated with the user who created the comment, you can use `$comment->uid`, and pass it to `user_load()`.
In fact, `template_preprocess_comment()` contains the following code, which means that `$comment->uid` is the user ID of the user who created the comment; once compared with `$variables['node']->uid`, the code is able to say that the comment was created by the node author.

```
if ($comment->uid == $variables['node']->uid) {
  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'comment-by-node-author';
}
```